# Synonym access in Oracle

Tags: oracle, synonym

How to access a synonym Z defined in Schema A in Schema B ?

```
Example - //CREATING TABLE X IN SCHEMA B FROM SYNONYM Z DEFINED IN SCHEMA A
 CREATE TABLE B.X(SELECT * FROM A.Z);

//THIS SYNTAX GIVES ERROR : TABLE DOESN'T EXIST
```

Comment: Synonym not be mixed with prefixing schema name. they are names referring to objects in a schema. it can be either public across all schemas, or private to one schema. In your case, if Z is synonym referring table Z in schema A. Just refer it as Z. provided the user has access to table Z n schema A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

If a synonym exists in schema A, it is by definition a private synonym.  Private synonyms are, well, private.

If you want to create a table in schema B, you'd need to access the base object (i.e. whatever object the synonyms in schema A is actually pointing to).  Given that synonyms do not grant any privileges, you'd still need access to the underlying table even if you could access the private synonym in A.  Given that, there would be no benefit to being able to access the private synonym in A, it would just add another layer of indirection for no apparent benefit.